# Volley request based on the system time android

Tags: android, session, android-volley

I am new to android.I have predefined session structure in the database as below:

```
1 | 9 AM - 12 PM | Breakfast
2 | 12 PM - 4 PM | Lunch
3 | 6 PM - 8 PM  | Snacks
4 | 9 PM - 12 AM | Dinner
```

I will be making a volley request to the database, if the time set on my android device is between the session `1` then it shall take the value as `Breakfast` and when the time on my device gets changed to next session corresponding value of the session should be taken automatically. How to do this?? Any help will be appreciated. :)